# Алгоритм удаления слов из текста

Tags: c, алгоритм

Задание состоит в том, что есть текст заранее неизвестного размера, в котором необходимо удалить слова, которые содержатся отдельно в текстовом файле в формате
^слово (удаление первого слова или предложения целого)
^10слово (удаление первых 10 слов или предложений)
#слово (удаление 10 первых слов с конца)
#10слово (удаление 10 первых слов/предложений с конца)
слово (удаление всех совпадающих слов/предложений)

Значений в конфигурационном файле может быть сколько угодно и в любом порядке. Собственно вопрос, какой алгоритм для удаления слов является наиболее эффективным, я реализовал поиск слов и удаления с помощью алгоритма КМП, но это очень долго. Есть идея попробовать сделать через линейные списки, сохраняя в каждом поле слово и удаляя, обходя элемент лс. Есть ли какие-то алгоритмы про которые стоило бы почитать для решения этой задачи?
Спасибо!

Comment: Не очень понятно, из какого текста, его размер... Удаление именно первых/последних слов? Из вашего вопроса непонятно, где в задаче требуется поиск слов. Сформулируйте задание поточнее... Можете привести свой код - может дело в нем.

Comment: @Harry, сейчас поправлю

Comment: @Harry, код, который уже написан работает так, как требуется, но мне кажется, что есть способы решения задачи эффективней :)

Comment: мне кажется, что автор вопроса пытается сделать свой sed.

Comment: А что значит "долго работает"? Какого размера текст? (по порядку величины - килобайты, гигабайты?) Надо ли выполнять *все* действия, указанные в файле (т.е. если указаны 20 слов в разных строках, то их в принципе можно искать с помощью алгоритма Ахо-Корасик). Но что-то мне говорит, что вряд ли задание будет такое сложное, чтобы пришлось прибегнуть к таким хитростям, и обычного `strstr` должно хватать :)

Comment: @Harry, текст размером ~200 мб, нужно выполнять все, что указано

Comment: Но если я правильно понял задачу, то тут вся суть не в хитрых алгоримах, а в правильной структуре данных. Я бы сделал массив структур, внутри которых массив слов (а может просто строка, надо подумать) + мета данные - количесво слов в строке. И теперь удалить последние десять слов будет очень легко. Главное не забыть обновить метадату. Также, можно даже распараллеливать все это. Удалить слово с номером 100500? нет проблем - бежим по внешнему массиву и суммируем кол-во строк пока не подберемся к нужному. А дальше элементарно. Ну а в конце нужно сделать обычный join.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо!